# Vue замена текста на компонент

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

Есть строка
 text : string = 'Завтра в городе #msk будет хорошая похода'
Как в vue заменить некоторые слова в компонент?

Сейчас:

```
<p>{{text}}</p>

<p>Завтра в городе #msk будет хорошая похода</p>
```

Что должно в итоге получится:

```
<p>{{text}}</p>

<p>Завтра в городе <tag :tagid='#msk'>#msk</tag> будет хорошая похода</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

по хорошему вам надо еще помимо текста передавать динамический параметр.

Посему будет так:

```
<p>{{text}}</p>

<p>Завтра в городе <tag :tagid='msk'>{{msk}}</tag> будет хорошая похода</p>
```

И vue не будет рендерить такую запись:

`<tag tagid='#msk'>#msk</tag>`

Он выведет ее как обычний `html` элемент

**UPDATE**
Вам нужно использовать [фильтры](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html)

Вот здесь рабочий вариант
https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-water-ogfg3

воздаем фильтр в директиве:

```
 filters: {
    replaceTags(value, tag, replasor) {
      let re = new RegExp(tag);
      return value.replace(
        re,
        `<tag style="color:red;" tagid='${replasor}'>${replasor}</tag>`
      );
    }
  }
```

Который принимает 3 параметра, по названию думаю поймёте

Comment: Допустим id это #msk, да я там двоеточие пропустил (отредактировал). Так как сделать то? Любые {{text.replace('#msk', '<tag>')}} просто выводит как текст , компонент не подставляется

Comment: @padavan https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-payne-021bw
C `replace` - это вам посоветовали скрестить ужа и ежа

Comment: Вы не так поняли (или я плохо объяснил) вопрос. У меня есть список этих текстов , их может быть очень много, в тексте могут быть тэги или отсутствовать. Как в тексте попадается ключевое слово, то оно должно заменяться на компонент  (у него будут свои стили , экшены). Я обновил ваш пример, вот что нужно сделать: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-curran-zdh3v?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: уже знаю решение, но пока нет времени написать. позже постараюсь приложить ссылку

Comment: @padavan обновил ответ. если что -то не ясно пишите

Comment: по вашей ссылки компонент , как компонент не работает. Вот в компоненте написано что при клике вызывается alert это не происходит.